# Difference between Apache Taglibs and Glassfish JSTL's implementation?

Tags: java, maven, jstl, taglib

In order to use JSTL (JSP taglibs) in a maven project, one needs to import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet, that's not enough since this is only an API. One solution is to uses [Glassfish's implementation](http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/), another is to use [Apache Taglibs](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/).

What is the difference between both and which one is recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both support JSDL 1.2 now. <strike>The Glassfish one supports JSTL 1.2 whereas Apache's supports 1.1 with "1.2 in the works" - since 2009, which in my opinion could mean that the project was sort of abandoned</strike>.  I already transplanted the GF one into Tomcat (as most of our work is GF based it was the easiest one to borrow) and didn't encounter problems, but I may just have been lucky :-)

EDIT: wrt JSTL1.1 vs 1.2, quoting from the [Oracle JSTL page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

> The JSTL 1.2 Maintenance Release aligns with the Unified Expression
>   Language (EL) that is being delivered as part of the JavaServer Pages
>   (JSP) 2.1 specification. Thanks to the Unified EL, JSTL tags, such as
>   the JSTL iteration tags, can now be used with JavaServer Faces
>   components in an intuitive way.

Comment: Is there a substantial benefit of using JSTL 1.2 over 1.1?

Comment: So whats the situation now, 3 years later?
https://jstl.java.net/download.html seems to be broken.
glassfish has:"org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:1.2.4"
apache has "org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:1.2.5"
are these related, the same, does one have advantages, etc?

Comment: @JohnCaron As both the GF version and Apache version implement JSTL 1.2, they should offer the same functionality, so the one that's "best" for you is probably more a convenience thing than anything else.